# Using ffmpeg to convert files to OVG (libtheora) on Windows 10 results in corrupted Video Files

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, windows

> ```
> ffmpeg version 4.2.2 win64 static
> ```

I'm using this command in Windows 10 to convert a file from mp4 to ogv:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libtheora -q:v 10 -c:a libvorbis -q:a 10 output.ogv
```

The result is a jumbled mess of colors:

[image: Snapshot of corrupted .ogv video]

However, when executing the same command on Ubuntu(20.04 LTS) it works just fine.

The pic shown is a snapshot of the result played in VLC. When playing the same video in Windows' “Film & TV” application, it just skips the frames that have these artifacts (which is very often).

Any idea what could cause this Windows specific problem?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but why output the old, legacy Theora + Vorbis in OGV instead of VP9 + Opus in WebM?

Comment: @llogan The reason is because I'm using the OGV format for a project in the Godot Engine. You see, WebM is a problematic format in Godot Engine(specifically on Linux). It has problems such as not being able to play WebM videos that have a framerate above 30.

Such problems do not exist in the OGV format for the Godot Engine.

Comment: Please provide the complete log from the command. Does the issue occur with all files, or only certain ones? To clarify, does the video output from Windows also look bad on Ubuntu? Does the same output video look bad on VLC on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this thread: https://old.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/fy2618/need_someone_to_test_libtheora_encoder_on_64bit/
The theora encoder is currently broken in the 64bits versions.
I tried this with the 32bits version and it now works as expected.

32bits builds can be found here: https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/

Greetings